# CVS - local repository, on Windows Server 2016 - how to do this?

Tags: cvs

I am not a CVS expert (I have a little more knowledge in GIT), but at this point we continue to use CVS for some projects (and cannot change that for now).

Our Jenkins build system has a few jobs that use CVS.  I need to modify them in respect to tagging and branching.  In my testing, I do not want to possibly screw up the production repositories, so I want to create a local copy of some of the modules in the remote CVS repository, and test with them.

I do not have any CVS Server products installed on this system, and am getting the impression that without this, I cannot init a local repository, so that I can then populate it (I do not need to checkout from the remote repository, as I already have the files).  I guess the first question is, do I need such a product to do a CVS init on Windows?

There seems to be plenty of links to CVS on OS's other than Windows, and links for Windows that are connecting to a remote CVS server and doing checkouts, but I cannot find a link that is specific for Windows, for initializing and populating a local repository.  In TortoiseCVS, I selected Local mounted folder, it is asking for a repository folder (which does not exist because I cannot get CVS init to work).  I know how to use TortoiseCVS to connect to the remote server , and checkout...but I want a local repository.

So, can someone either point me to a link that will help me with this, or, send me the 'how to'?   Thanks.

Comment: Even me too looking out for an answer